# query string in php url which fetches values from files in directories

Tags: php, include

for security reasons we need to disable a php/mysql for a non-profit site as it has a lot of vulnerabilities. It's a small site so we want to just rebuild the site without database and bypass the vulnerability of an admin page.

The website just needs to stay alive and remain dormant. We do not need to keep updating the site in future so we're looking for a static-ish design.

Our current URL structure is such that it has query strings in the url which fetches values from the database.

e.g. artist.php?id=2

I'm looking for a easy and quick way change artist.php so instead of fetching values from a database it would just include data from a flat html file so.

```
artist.php?id=1  = fetch data from /artist/1.html
artist.php?id=2  = fetch data from /artist/2.html
artist.php?id=3  = fetch data from /artist/3.html
artist.php?id=4  = fetch data from /artist/4.html
artist.php?id=5  = fetch data from /artist/5.html
```

The reason for doing it this way is that we need to preserve the URL structure for SEO purposes. So I do not want to use the html files for the public.

What basic php code would I need to achieve this?

Comment: I thought you want to disable php? Then the question needs to get updated ("What basic php code would I need to achieve this?") 


^^ And to achieve this - is htaccess available? If yes - You could do a redirect with a htaccess-rule.

Comment: Sorry, probably didn't do a good job of explaining myself. There is something wrong in the software/some vulnerability that malware hackers are using to expllit the site and inject code into it. We think it's most likely the admin section which is compromised and is allowing using to inject code into the site. The non-profit which I volunteer for does not have any budget to hire a programmer so I am just going to use my proposed method to get everything to "work" on the surface but remove all the admin and malware vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it exactly as you ask would be like this:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$page = file_get_contents("/artist/$id.html");
```

In case `$id === 0` there was something else besides numbers in the query parameter. You could also have the artist information in an array:

```
// datafile.php
return array(
    1 => "Artist 1 is this and that",
    2 => "Artist 2..."
)
```

And then in your artist.php

```
$data = include('datafile.php');
if (array_key_exists($_GET['id'], $data)) {
    $page = $data[$_GET['id']];
} else {
    // 404
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the first paragraph of code did the job. I don't really know anything about php just know enough of what echo, vairables are and the opening and closing tags of php. The first para didn't really work until I put echo $page on the third line.

Comment: @AbdulKarim Glad to hear it helped! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML isn't your best option, but its cousin is THE BEST for static data files.

Let me introduce you to XML! (documentation to [PHP parser](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.xml.php))

XML is similar to HTML as structure, but it's made to store data rather than webpages.

If instead your html pages are already completed and you just need to serve them, you can use the url rewriting from your webserver (if you're using Apache, see [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

At last, a pure PHP solution (which I don't recommend)

```
<?php

//protect from displaying unwanted webpages or other vulnerabilities:
//we NEVER trust user input, and we NEVER use it directly without checking it up.
$valid_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5 /*etc*/);
if(in_array($_REQUEST['id'])){
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
} else {
  echo "missing artist!"; die;
}
//read the html file
$html_page = file_get_contents("/artist/$id.html");

//display the html file
echo $html_page;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, the html files are already written out so it's a bit too late to change them now. However - I want to thank you for contributing and you also helped me debug why Schlaus' code wasn't working for me as he was missing an echo.

Comment: @AbdulKarim remember to upvote every answer that's useful for you, one way or another, and to accept the one that solved your problem. It's better if you wait at least 24h before accepting though, because you may receive even better answers.

Comment: thanks i tried to upvote both of your answers, however it says I njeed at least 15 rep.